# "Was" use identification

Tags: grammar-identification, subordinate-clause

> **Was Eure merkwürdigen Empfindungen beim Schrein angeht,** ich denke, dass sich dort ein Teil der Verderbnis eingenistet hat, die die gesamte Insel der Sonnenwanderer bedroht.

what's the relation of this clause to the sentence? is this a relativsatz? why is the next clause, the hauptsatz, not starting with the verb? (I got this from a game, could it be ungrammatical?) I know the uses of the relative `was` but i cant seem to match one of them to this case. thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmmm... I've noticed `was... angeht` means "with regards to".... could it just be a fixed expression here? (and has nothing to do with relative `was` uses?)

Answer (score 3):

Correct word order would be:

"Was Eure merkwürdigen Empfindungen beim Schrein angeht, denke ich, dass ..."

The word order in the quote is a common (i.e., made by native speakers) mistake in spoken language. It might be intended to signal spoken language, e.g., if the quote is from a novel.

Actually, in spoken language there is usually a long break like:

"Was Eure merkwürdigen Empfindungen beim Schrein angeht ... Ich denke, dass sich dort ein Teil der Verderbnis eingenistet hat."

So, maybe I shouldn't strictly call it wrong.

Comment: the quote is from a game (fantasy themed). and this is a NPC talking (to the player)

Comment: You could also write a colon after "angeht", then it would be followed by a main clause and the word order "ich denke" would be correct.